# Computing group means for categories with no observations in dplyr and data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset with a numeric variable and a grouping variable, and would like to compute the group means. Some groups are empty, i.e. there are some factor levels that do not appear in the data. When computing the grouped means, I'd like to have these empty groups listed alongside the non-empty groups. This is easy to achieve using base R:

```
# Create an example of a data frame where variable1 is numeric and variable2 is a
# factor with three levels, two of which appear in the data:
df <- data.frame(variable1 = c(1,2,3,4), variable2 = factor(c("A","B","A","B")))
levels(df$variable2) <- c(levels(df$variable2), "C")

# Base R
tapply(df$variable1, df$variable2, mean)
```

which renders the output

```
A  B  C 
2  3 NA
```

which is what I'm looking for.

However, for various reasons I need to do this using either `dplyr` or `data.table` instead. The problem is that both skip the empty levels in the summaries:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(variable2) %>%
  summarise(var1Mean = mean(variable1))
```

yields

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  variable2 var1Mean
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 A                2
2 B                3
```

And

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, mean(variable1), variable2]
```

yields

```
   variable2 V1
1:         A  2
2:         B  3
```

Is there a way to make either of these packages include the empty groups in the summary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `.drop = FALSE` in `group_by` to keep empty groups.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
 group_by(variable2, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
 summarise(var1Mean = mean(variable1))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  variable2 var1Mean
#  <fct>        <dbl>
#1 A                2
#2 B                3
#3 C              NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in `data.table`

```
df[.(variable2 = levels(variable2)), on = 'variable2',
   mean(variable1), by = variable2]
#    variable2 V1
# 1:         A  2
# 2:         B  3
# 3:      <NA> NA
```

Slightly cleaner if `df` is keyed by `variable2`:

```
setkey(df, variable2)
df[.(levels(variable2)), mean(variable1), by = variable2]
```

Comment: Nice! It appears that this only works if there only is one empty group though. If I increase the number of empty groups, `levels(df$variable2) <- c(levels(df$variable2), "C", "D")`, this still only yields one row (`<NA> NA`). Also, it says `NA` instead of `C` in the summary.